# Random with specific integers

Tags: c#, random

I am writing a program for myself and i need to do a random between specific numbers.
not a random in the field between 2 numbers, A random between few specific numbers.
I want to do it with 15 different numbers but if someone could give me an example with just a few that would be wonderful!

Comment: Give us an example of what you're trying to do.  As currently written, your question is too vague to be answerable.

Comment: `"i need to do a random between specific numbers. not a random in the field between 2 numbers"` And what's the difference between the two?

Answer (score 6):

Store your numbers in an array, and choose a random index:

```
var nums = new int[] { 1, 5, 7, 14, 17 };
var rand = new Random();
var randIndex = rand.Next(nums.Length);
var theRandomSelection = nums[randIndex];

// do something with theRandomSelection
```

Answer (score 6):

Just fill an array with your numbers and then pick the index randomly. Pseudocode:

```
int numbers = new List<int>(){1, 2, 4, 7, 8};

Random r = new Random();

int index = r.Next(numbers.Count);

int randomNumber = numbers[index];
```

Answer (score 2):

Hard to understand what is being asked for, but it sounds like this:

```
int[] values = new int[] {1,3,5,7};  
Random r = new Random();
int rInt = r.Next(0, values.Count);  
int selected = values[rint];
```

Answer (score 1):

Make a List of your 15 specific numbers. Get a random number between 1 and 15. Get the item in the list at the position specified by your random number.